# Array not being created in PHP

Tags: php

I'm reacquainting myself with PHP (version 7.3) after being away from it for many years and can't wait to hear what's behind these problems...

This is taking place within code I'm writing for an Elementor Pro custom action. The run() function is part of a class definition which extends an abstract method from \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Action_Base. I'm basically following the example code from https://developers.elementor.com/forms-api/custom-form-action/.

```
public function run( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
    $site_key   = get_option( 'elementor_pro_recaptcha_site_key' );
    $secret_key = get_option( 'elementor_pro_recaptcha_secret_key' );

    if ( ! $site_key || ! $secret_key ) {
        return;
    }

    $settings = $record->get( 'form_settings' );

    if ( empty( $settings['form_fields'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $form_fields = $settings['form_fields'];
    $junk = array('abc', 'def');
    $fields = array_column($form_fields, 'field_type');
    $email_index = array_search('email', $fields, true);
    $pw_index = array_search('password', $fields, true);

    if ( empty( $settings['password'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

$form_fields is an array whose values I can see in the debugger (I'm using PhpStorm). $fields is also an array which has two values, `email` and `message` in this case which I can also see in the debugger.

But $junk is undefined. Referencing it in the PhpStorm watch panel throws a "Cannot evaluate expression" error.

$email_index and $pw_index are also undefined. Even though I can see that `email` and `password` exist within $fields in the watch panel.

I am obviously doing something very basically wrong (the vast majority of my background is in C#). But I don't know what that is.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with how you're setting `$junk`.

Comment: Is this really your code, or is there more to it? Maybe there's a variable scope problem.

Comment: please post your `$settings['form_fields'];` array

Comment: just `print_r` everywhere, so that you'll able to see, what's going wrong!

Comment: I'll show the entire method in the edit. $settings['form_fields'] is quite large so unless you can explain why it needs to be included I'd rather follow up on suggestions regarding it.

Comment: All the fields you can't watch are set but never used, so it's likely they've been optimised out of existence.

Comment: Are you trying to use the variables after the function returns? Variables are local by default, you need to write `global $junk;` if you want it to be accessed outside the function.

Comment: If these are supposed to be class properties, you have to write `$this->junk`. PHP isn't like C++ or C##, it doesn't allow you to access properties as normal variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 7 performs static (SSA) optimization when converting your source to opcode. `$junk` isn't used within the scope, so PHP optimizes it out.

When debugging xdebug, this optimization should actually not happen (afaik). However, if you're using opcode caching, the already optimized opcode might be used. You should be able to solve it by disabling it.

```
opcache.enable = 0
```

---

For more information about SSA optimization in PHP 7, see [these slides by Nikita](https://www.slideshare.net/nikita_ppv/static-optimization-of-php-bytecode-phpsc-2017).

Comment: Thanx, @jasny! That did the trick. For the benefit of other php newbies, setting opcache.enable is done in the php.ini file, which you can find under Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> click the ellipsis to the right of the CLI Interpreter you've defined. I also had to restart the Apache web server for the change to take effect.